# Flux (alt), TabBarIOS, and Listeners and tabs that have not yet been touched / loaded

Tags: react-native

I've got a problem that I'm sure has a simple solution, but I'm new to React and React Native so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

My app has a TabBarIOS component at its root, with two tabs: TabA and TabB. TabB is subscribed to events from a Flux store (I'm using alt) that TabA creates. TabA basically enqueues items that TabB plays. This part of the code is fine and works as expected.

The problem is that TabA is the default tab so the user can use TabA an enqueue items, but because TabB hasn't been touched/clicked the TabB component hasn't been created so *it's listener hasn't been registered*. Only when TabB is pressed does it get created and correctly receive events.

So how can I ensure the TabB component gets created when the TabBarIOS component is rendered? Do I need to something hacky like set the active tab to TabB on initial load and flip it back to TabA before the user does anything?

Comment: Post link to source code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to do something hacky if you're not using a `Navigator` component. If you're using `Navigator`you can specify a set of routes to initially mount with the `initialRouteStack`prop. This is however going to need you to modify a bit the way your app works I think.

If not using Navigator, you'll indeed have to do something hacky as you suggested. I've set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/FIrMcg) based on RN's TabBar example.

Below you'll find the code of this example, check the `console.log` (they don't seem to work on *rnplay*) to see that that components are mounted on opening the app.

**Example Code**

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TabBarIOS,
  Text,
  View
} = React;

import _ from 'lodash';

var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

class StackOverflowApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'blueTab',
      notifCount: 0,
      presses: 0
    };
  }

  _renderContent = (color, pageText, num) => {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.tabContent, {backgroundColor: color}]}>
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>{pageText}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>{num} re-renders of the {pageText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({selectedTab: 'redTab'});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({selectedTab: 'blueTab'});
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TabBarIOS
          tintColor="white"
          barTintColor="darkslateblue">
          <TabBarIOS.Item
            title="Blue Tab"
            icon={{uri: base64Icon, scale: 3}}
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'blueTab'}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                selectedTab: 'blueTab',
              });
            }}>
            <Page1 />
          </TabBarIOS.Item>
          <TabBarIOS.Item
            systemIcon="history"
            badge={this.state.notifCount > 0 ? this.state.notifCount : undefined}
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'redTab'}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                selectedTab: 'redTab'
              });
            }}>
            <Page2 />
          </TabBarIOS.Item>
        </TabBarIOS>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

class Page1 extends Component {
  static route() {
    return {
      component: Page1
    }
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('page 1 mount');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('page 1 unmount');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.tabContent}>
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>Page 1</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends Component {
  static route() {
    return {
      component: Page2
    }
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('page 2 mount');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('page 2 unmount');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.tabContent}>
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>Page 2</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabContent: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  tabText: {
    color: 'white',
    margin: 50,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('StackOverflowApp', () => StackOverflowApp);
```